# Jenkins (Windows installation) screenshot resolution

Tags: selenium, jenkins

I have created a test which takes a screenshot of the page currently being tested and compares this to a known "good" image.

When I run this via Eclipse or Maventhe screenshots are generally the same resolution as my screen (I use window().maximise to make sure it is full screen) However with Jenkins the screenshots are smaller.

So, with Eclipse or Maven the screenshots are 1680x939, but with Jenkins the screens are 1024x697

I have seen one single post that says there is a registry key to set the screen resolution, but I can't find this documented anywhere.  Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I found an article which suggested that running the installed version of Jenkins may not allow access to certain system resources and to use the war file instead.  I disabled my Jenkins service and did this.  THe screenshots came down with the correct resolution.  Is this a known limitation of the windows installed Jenkins or is there a way around it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on the headless screen of the slave. Sometimes you even get a blank picture. What I did is install VNC server software (UtralVNC on Windows) on the slave (your test bed), and configure the resolution as you want first before you run your test. As long as the VNC service is running, you should be able to control the screen size

Comment: I'll need to give that one a try.  I found one post which stated there was a registry key that could control the headless size, but can't find any references to it.  So far, I've just used the war file and ran it that way